# Loop over columns of a data.frame to apply a condition

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a data.frame like this:

```
        name       value1      value2     value3   
          a          0.10         0.9       0.10
          b          0.00         0.3       0.67
          c          0.01         0.1       0.10
          d          0.12         0.10      0.2
          e          0.10         0.001     0.1
```

For each column "value*" I would like, the name corresponding to the value 0.10. In other words the output will be a data.frame of three columns containing elements of the "name". I started with the idea to cbind the "name" to each "value*" column to then subset but without success:

```
 for(i in 1:length(mydf)){    
      my_subset[[i]] = cbind(rownames(mydf), mydf[[i]])    
 }
```

the column "name" is rownames of mydf. Moreover I have totally 10.000 rows and 45 columns.

Desired output:

```
        name       value1      value2     value3   
          a          a           NA        a
          b          NA          NA        NA
          c          NA          NA        c
          d          NA          d         NA
          e          e           NA        NA
```

Can anyone help me please? I know there's some "apply" function probably able to do the job but I'm forcing to learn how to use for loops.

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you post your desired output?

Comment: I emphasis on the previous comment, and you can add the row names as a new column like this : `mydf$name_col <- rownames(mydf)`

Comment: Is 0.1 equal to 0.10?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative using a for loop

```
X <- data.frame(
    name = letters[1:5],
    value1 = c(0.10, 0.00, 0.01, 0.12, 0.10),
    value2 = c(0.90, 0.30, 0.10, 0.10, 0.001),
    value3 = c(0.10, 0.67, 0.10, 0.20, 0.10),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Example data:

```
X
```

```
  name value1 value2 value3
1    a   0.10  0.900   0.10
2    b   0.00  0.300   0.67
3    c   0.01  0.100   0.10
4    d   0.12  0.100   0.20
5    e   0.10  0.001   0.10
```

```
for (j in grep("value", names(X))) {
    X[, j] <- ifelse(X[, j] == 0.10, X[, "name"], NA)
}
```

Result:

```
X
```

```
  name value1 value2 value3
1    a      a   <NA>      a
2    b   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
3    c   <NA>      c      c
4    d   <NA>      d   <NA>
5    e      e   <NA>      e
```

Answer (score 3):

Is it this that you want?

```
a = structure(list(value1 = c("0.10", "0.00", "0.01", "0.12", "0.10"
), value2 = c("0.9", "0.3", "0.1", "0.10", "0.001"), value3 = c("0.10", 
"0.67", "0.10", "0.2", "0.1")), row.names = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e"), class = "data.frame")

val = "0.10"
apply(a,2,function(x) rownames(a)[which(x==val)])

$`value1`
[1] "a" "e"

$value2
[1] "d"

$value3
[1] "a" "c"
```

Comment: Why not c and d?

Comment: Yes it is! Nelson not c/d because the requirement is not >0.10 but equal

Comment: That means 0.1!=0.10 then!

Comment: @NelsonGon that is what I though and that is why I treated the value as `character`

Answer (score 2):

With base R `lapply`

```
cols <- grep("^value", names(df))
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) ifelse(x == 0.1, df$name, NA))


df
#  name value1 value2 value3
#1    a      a   <NA>      a
#2    b   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
#3    c   <NA>      c      c
#4    d   <NA>      d   <NA>
#5    e      e   <NA>      e
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized approach with `base R`

```
df[-1] <- df$name[NA^(df[-1] != 0.1) * seq_len(nrow(df))]
df
#    name value1 value2 value3
#1    a      a   <NA>      a
#2    b   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
#3    c   <NA>      c      c
#4    d   <NA>      d   <NA>
#5    e      e   <NA>      e
```

#### Benchmarks

```
df1 <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), 1e7), ]

df2 <- copy(df1)

system.time({
cols <- grep("^value", names(df1))
df1[cols] <- lapply(df1[cols], function(x) ifelse(x == 0.1, df1$name, NA))
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#  35.700   4.587  40.615 
system.time({
 df2[-1] <- df2$name[NA^(df2[-1] != 0.1) * seq_len(nrow(df2))]

})
#   user  system elapsed 
# 21.709   3.886  26.026
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), value1 = c(0.1, 
 0, 0.01, 0.12, 0.1), value2 = c(0.9, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.001), value3 = c(0.1, 
  0.67, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by using `data.table` package-

```
> setDT(dt)[,(setdiff(colnames(dt),"name")):=lapply(.SD,function(x) ifelse(x==.10,as.character(name),NA)),.SDcols=setdiff(colnames(dt),"name")]

> dt
   name value1 value2 value3
1:    a      a   <NA>      a
2:    b   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
3:    c   <NA>      c      c
4:    d   <NA>      d   <NA>
5:    e      e   <NA>      e
```